# InfluxDB и telegraf сбор данных ротация

Tags: linux, файловая-система, influxdb

почувствовав себя тру админом, воткнул influxDB и telegraf, статистика собирается с 5 серверов в одно место, разбудило меня сегодня тревожное сообщения что на одном из серверов (на том самом с influxDB ) осталось 70% в рутовой fs, увидев что influxdb сожрала аж 40ГБ спейса (за 5 дней), задался вопросом о ротации. Удалять все данные бы все таки не хотелось, может кто то поделиться магией или способами, или хотябы идеями...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfluxDB умеет сама чистить старые записи. Для этого вам нужно настроить *Continuous Queries (CQ)* и *Retention Policies (RP)* для ваших таблиц. Начать можно с такого:

```
CREATE RETENTION POLICY "two_hours" ON "my_database" DURATION 2h REPLICATION 1 DEFAULT;
CREATE RETENTION POLICY "a_year" ON "my_database" DURATION 52w REPLICATION 1;
```

CQ следует писать для ваших данных, ведь только вы знаете что и как следует сокращать и как хранить. [Примеры запросов для telegraf.](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/687)

[Более подробно в документации.](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/guides/downsampling_and_retention/) Если вы не можете понять что тут нужно сделать, то подумайте: может вам не нужна InfluxDB, а подойдёт какой-нибудь старый, проверенный временем, [collectd](https://collectd.org/) в связке с Graphite.

Answer (score 0):

1. Сжатие.
2. Посмотрите, вся ли вам статистика так нужна?
3. Сжатые данные, которые не нужны вам постоянно, отправляйте в облако. 300 гб не будут вам многового стоить.